# how to setup the .htaccess for a subdomain on a shared hosting godaddy server

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I want to upload my local Laravel project on godaddy but I'm having some error

error

```
[Wed Jul 05 21:16:44.858396 2017] 
    [autoindex:error] [pid 21796:tid 139689709188864] 
    [client 99.240.235.234:57754] 
    AH01276: 
        Cannot serve directory /home/bugsbunny/public_html/sto.com/: 
            No matching DirectoryIndex (/home/bugsbunny/public_html/sto.com/public/index.php) 
    found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex /home/bugsbunny/public_html/sto.com/public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /home/bugsbunny/public_html/sto.com/public/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

steps that I did

- I edited the public/.htaccess file
- by edited I mean changing the directory on the first line and the line starting by `RewriteRule`
- I cut & paste this file into the root directory
- I uploaded the project into godaddy

Answer (score 0):

On Godaddy I find it easier to create/upload a Laravel app with this procedure

```
1- Create an addon domain or a sub-domain on Godaddy
2- Install a Laravel app (Quick-install) on this domain/sub-domain
3- Download this app on local (my computer) with Filezilla (or other sftp software)
4- On local disk change the .env database access or (create a user+password+database on phpmyadmin/mysql with the information contain in the .env that Godaddy setup for you)
5- finish up the app (Build the webapp project that you want to do).
6- Upload the app to the server (except the .env) with Filezilla
7- upload the database (mysql) from local to Godaddy
```

So there is no need to change the .htaccess file.

Answer (score -1):

Why you are not using dedicated hosting for laravel. Get your server and [digitaloccean, etc] and do what you want...